# Question about Dirac operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, sp.spectral-theory

Let $D$ be a generalized Dirac operator on a complete Riemannian manifold. I'm a little confused to prove that there exists a constant $c>0$ such that

$$\|D\sigma\|^2\geq c^2\|\sigma\|^2$$

for $\sigma\in H_+\equiv \bigoplus\limits_{0<|\lambda|\leq c}E_\lambda$. Here $E_\lambda$ is the eigenspace of $D$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

I'm not sure if this question is too easy for math overflow. Could you give me some help with the details? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Express $\sigma$ in an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors.

Comment: Could you please write down your idea with some details? I can't follow you. Thanks a lot.@Echo

Comment: If $\sigma=\sum_i\mu_if_i$ with $Df_i=\lambda_if_i$, then $\parallel D\sigma\parallel^2=\sum_i|\mu_i|^2|\lambda_i|^2\ge\sum_ic^2|\mu_i|^2=c^2\parallel \sigma\parallel^2$

Comment: Excuse me, I checked your calculation and I think it should be $|\lambda_i|^2\leq c^2$ for $\sigma\in H_+$. @Echo

Comment: Oh sorry, I read the inequality the other way round. But see, only this way your claim is true, otherwise it is false. Or did you mean $\le$ in your claim?

Comment: I'm sure that the inequality is $\geq$. And I guess we can take the $c=\min\{\lambda_i\}$ to make our claim hold. Does it right?@Echo

Comment: There seem to be two different c's here.

Comment: These c's are the same one. And I was confused about if the minimum of $\lambda_i$s' is a constant, not a function. @Echo

Comment: How can c be the minimum of the $\lambda$ which satisfy $|\lambda|\le c$?

Comment: With the original $\leq$ and $\geq$ the statement is certanly false. Take as counterexample the disjoint union of countably many S^2 of different radius. It is also not really a question about Dirac operators, but about operators in general. Thus the question is not really well-posed.